# To-do list works in the console, but not on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm making a to-do list application with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

I've got a button listed after each to-do (actually a `span`). When the user clicks the `span` it should currently gets the id of the span ready to pass to the delete function (which I haven't written yet).

Here is the click event:

```
$(".delete").click(function(e) {
    var clickedtodelete = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log("Deleting " + clickedtodelete);
});
```

When I test the page, I click a span with the class of `.delete` and should get to the console the following output: `Deleting Test To-Do`. However, nothing happens.

I do, however, get the correct output to the console if I first type the click event into the console manually. Thus, it can only be an error with getting the script from the page.
All of the other scripts from the same .js page work, however.

Finally, I get a [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) type warning, but I have been told that that will not affect it.

Comment: Are you using `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ });`?

Comment: yes I am, however, the problem is solved, but thanks anyway

Comment: please could someone say why this question is downvoted?

Comment: @dKen Please could you tell me why this question was downvoted so i can fix it?

Comment: Not sure, I didn't downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a to-do list, I imagine the items are being generated dynamically. I suspect that the cause of your problem is that the click events are being bound before the elements you wish to bind them to exist. You can solve this using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)'s `on()` method like so:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function(e) {
        var clickedtodelete = $(this).attr("id"); 
        console.log("Deleting " + clickedtodelete);
    }
}, '.delete');
```

With this solution, the event is attached to the document (which always exists) and simply checks the target every time it receives an event. This allows events to be added dynamically.

Comment: Thanks that solved it I will accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are added dynamically, you have to use delegation:

```
$(document).on("click",".delete", function (e) {
    var clickedtodelete = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log("Deleting " + clickedtodelete);
});
```

Or you are not waiting for DOM ready:

```
$(function(){...});
```

Or you could put your handler code just before the body closing tag:

```
<script>
$(".delete").click(function (e) {
    var clickedtodelete = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log("Deleting " + clickedtodelete);
});
</script>
</body>
```